# The radius of a circle, having minimum area, which touches the curve $y = 4 - x^2$ and the lines, $y = |x|$ is

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry, circles

The radius of a circle, having minimum area, which touches the curve $y = 4 - x^2$ and the lines, $y = |x|$ is

My attempt is as follows:-

Let the circle be $x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$, let the line $y=x$ touching circle at $(\alpha,\alpha)$

$$y\alpha+x\alpha+g(x+\alpha)+f(y+\alpha)+c=0$$
$$x(\alpha+g)+y(\alpha+f)+g\alpha+f\alpha+c=0$$

Comparing it with $y=x$

$$\dfrac{1}{\alpha+f}=\dfrac{-1}{\alpha+g}$$

$$\alpha+g=-\alpha-f=2\alpha+g+f=0\tag{1}$$
$$g\alpha+f\alpha+c=0$$
$$g+f=-\dfrac{c}{\alpha}$$
$$-2\alpha=-\dfrac{c}{\alpha}$$
$$2\alpha^2=c\tag{2}$$

Comparing it with $y=-x$, let the line $y=-x$ touching circle at $\left(\beta,-\beta\right)$

$$-y\beta+x\beta+g(x+\beta)+f(y-\beta)+c=0$$
$$x(g+\beta)+y(f-\beta)+g\beta-f\beta+c=0$$

$$\dfrac{1}{f-\beta}=\dfrac{1}{g+\beta}$$
$$f-g=2\beta$$
$$g\beta-f\beta+c=0$$
$$\beta(g-f)=-c$$
$$2\beta^2=c$$

So we got $\alpha=\pm\beta$

Let the parametric point on $y=4-x^2$ be $(\gamma,4-\gamma^2)$

$$y-(4-\gamma^2)=-2\gamma(x-\gamma)$$
$$y-4+\gamma^2=-2\gamma x+2\gamma^2$$
$$y-4=-2\gamma x+\gamma^2$$

Let's write the equation of tangent to circle at point $(\gamma,4-\gamma^2)$

$$y(4-\gamma^2)+x\gamma+g(x+\gamma)+f(y+4-\gamma^2)+c=0$$
$$y(4-\gamma^2+f)+x(\gamma+g)+g\gamma+f(4-\gamma^2)+c=0$$

$$\dfrac{1}{4-\gamma^2+f}=\dfrac{2\gamma}{\gamma+g}$$

Its getting too long, any other way of doing this question?

Comment: The given situation is that there are a lot of circles touching the straight line and the parabola...and the query is to pick out the smallest one from  among them. Right?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Given the symmetry with respect to the $y$-axis,let the equation of the circle be

$$x^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$$

Note that the origin, the center of the circle and the touch point with one of the lines $y=|x|$ form a 45-45 right triangle, which gives

$$ b = \sqrt2 r\tag 1$$

Also, match the gradients at the touch point with the curve $y=4-x^2$,

$$ y' = -2x = -\frac{x}{y-b}$$

which leads to $y = \frac12 + b$. Plug it into $y=4-x^2$ to get $x$-coordinates of the touch points $x=\pm\sqrt{\frac72-b}$. Then, the distance of the center to the touch points is

$$(\frac72 -b) + \frac14 = r^2=\frac{b^2}2$$

where (1) is used in the last step. solve to obtain $b  = \sqrt{\frac{17}2}-1$ 
and, in turn, the radius

$$r = \frac12(\sqrt{17}-\sqrt2)$$

Comment: but how can we say that it touches the given curve at $(0,4)$

Comment: @user3290550 - you're right. it doesn't. fixed it

Comment: but answer is $4(\sqrt{2}-1)$

Comment: in the question they are asking radius of circle of minimum area

Comment: @user3290550 - $4(\sqrt2-1)$ is the result of the maximum circle area, when the circle touches $y=4-x^2$ at $(0,4)$

Comment: but we have to calculate radius of circle with minimum area, in your solution how you are ensuring this condition.

Comment: @user3290550 - there are only two possibilities, one with the touch point at (0,4) for the maximum area and the other given in the answer for the minimum area

Comment: @Quanto why would the one touching at (0,4) be maximum area? the one of maximum area would touch the parabola at the point (0,4) and y =|x| at the point (0,0). This would be the maximum right?

Comment: @Sid - I interpret touching as being tangential to each others