# The radius of a circle, having maximum area, which touches the curve $y = 4 – x^2$ and the lines, $y = |x|$ is

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, circles

The radius of a circle, having maximum area, which touches the curve $y = 4 – x^2$ and the lines, $y = |x|$ is

Note this is different from: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3541010/the-radius-of-a-circle-having-minimum-area-which-touches-the-curve-y-4-x) which is asking for minimum area.

If you click on the link and see the comments section of the answer the person said the area of the circle with maximum area touches the parabola at (0,4) and intersects the parabola at two other points and along with this touches the curve y = |x| at two distinct points.

My question is: isn't the circle with maximum area the one touching the parabola at (0,4) and touching the curve y=|x| at (0,0)? Can we call such a circle touching both y=|x| and the parabola?

Here is a diagram:

[image: diagram]

Here purple is the line y =|x|, green is the parabola, black is the circle with minimum radius (which I agree with) and red is the one they are claiming to be circle with the maximum radius which I'm not sure. Shouldn't it be the circle $x^2 + (y-2)^2 = 4$? That circle touches y=|x| at (0,0) and parabola at (0,4). The only difference is the derivative at the touching point isn't the same. What is right? Please clarify.

Comment: $x^2 + (y-2)^2 = 4$ is not "touching" $y=|x|$.

Comment: @Koro ok so touching implies the derivative must be the same?

Comment: Please refer my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer should be the circle touching y=|x| and y=4-$x^2$ from above with r=  4(1+$\sqrt2$). Its radius is larger than 4($\sqrt2$-1), which is the radius of the other circle touching the parabola from underneath.

As shown in the graph, let r= radius of the circle centered at o'(0,x+r) , the circle touches y=x at A(x,x).

With  $\Delta$ OO'A, $(4+r)^2$=$r^2$+$(\sqrt2x)^2$

With $\Delta$ BO'A, $(4+r-x)^2+x^2$=$r^2$

Solving these two equations,

x($x^2-8x+8)=0, $r=$\frac{x^2-8}{4}$

Only solution x=4+2$\sqrt2$, r=4(1+$\sqrt2$) provides positive r.
[image]

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The equation of the circle touching  $y=\pm x$ and center on $y$-axis be
$$x^2+(y-h)^2=h^2/2~~~(1)$$
Now if ith has to touch $y=4-x^2$, then the equation
$$4-y+(y-h)^2=h^2/2 \implies y^2-(2h+1)y+h^2/2+4=0$$ should have a unique root of $y$. Imposing $B^2=4AC$, we get
$$2h^2+4h-15=0 \implies h=\frac{-4\pm \sqrt{136}}{4}$$
Choosing positive value we have $h=\frac{\sqrt{136}-4}{4}$ in (1).

For the other possibility, (1) should give $y(0)=4$ and $h<4$.
This gives $(4-h)^2-h^2/2 \implies h(1\pm 1/\sqrt{2})=4$, we get
$$h=\frac{4 \sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}\pm1}~~~~(2)$$, in (1), choosing $+$ sign.

**EDIT**
So maximum radius from (2)  $$r=h/\sqrt{2}=\frac{4}{\sqrt{2}-1}.$$
as found by @Bright Star, below.

Comment: ok so the maximum radius is: $r=\frac{4 }{\sqrt{2}+1}$?

Comment: @Sid, please see my answer, is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @BrightStar brilliant. yeah. thats cool. let  me just check. i never thought of it that way.

Comment: @Bright is right I have edited my answer.

Comment: @Ahmed, it’s great you kill two birds with one stone!UP vote

Answer (score 1):

Two curves $y=f(x)$ and $y= g(x)$ are said to be touching at $(x_0,y_0)$ if $y_0=f(x_0)=g(x_0)$ and $f'(x_0)=g'(x_0)$.

In your case:  Indeed the circle $x^2 + (y-2)^2 = 4$ and straight lines $y=|x|$ meet at $(0,0)$ but the function $y=|x|$ does not have a unique tangent at $(0,0)$.